# How to group array of objects and keep other keys in output

Tags: python, group-by, counter

I have the following collection:

```
array = [
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'key': 'val3', 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'key': 'val2', 'another_key': 'd'},
  {'key': 'val3', 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
]
```

I want to group by `key1` with count of objects.
For the above example, I want to get one of next options:

```
[
  {'val1': 3, 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'val3': 2, 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'val2': 1, 'another_key': 'd'},
]

[
  {'key':'val1', count: 3, 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'key':'val3', count: 2, 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'key':'val2', count: 1, 'another_key': 'd'},
]
```

I want to use the `Counter` module.

My code:

```
from collections import Counter 

groups = Counter([a['key'] for a in array])
groups = groups.most_common()
```

But I get only first key...

```
>>> groups
[('val1', 3), ('val3', 2), ('val2', 1)]
```

How can I get also the another key in one of the above formats?

Comment: Does the output  need to be a Counter or can it be used as a temporal storage and then store it in the format you gave us? If it needs to be a Counter, can we change the output format in some way?

Comment: Can be temporal storage

Comment: If 2 array elements have the same `key` will they also have the same `another_key`?

Comment: Yes. I have more keys but I need only those 2, which are the same.

Comment: @user2503775 just posted an answer that keep the format you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no answer gave you the output format you asked for, here you are:

```
counter = Counter((item['key'], item['another_key']) for item in array)
groups = [{t[0]: count, 'another_key': t[1]} for t, count in counter.most_common()]
```

This solution gives you the first answer format you suggested.

The second format could be obtained changing the second row by:

```
groups = [{'count': count, 'key': t[0], 'another_key': t[1]} for t, count in counter.most_common()]
```

As [@PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237959/5612096) posted later, if you don't need it sorted `counter.most_common()` can be swapped for `counter.items()`.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't notice your answer until after I'd posted mine.

Comment: @PM2Ring we may be both writting at the same time, don't you worry

Answer (score 1):

Just put the keys you want to preserve into a hashable collection; a tuple is perfect for this. Then you can easily build the new dicts by iterating over the tuples and associated counts in the Counter.

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

arr = [
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
  {'key': 'val3', 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'key': 'val2', 'another_key': 'd'},
  {'key': 'val3', 'another_key': 'c'},
  {'key': 'val1', 'another_key': 'a'},
]

groups = Counter((d['key'], d['another_key']) for d in arr)

new_arr = [{'key': t[0], 'another_key': t[1], 'count': val} 
    for t, val in groups.items()]

pprint(new_arr)
```

**output**

```
[{'another_key': 'd', 'count': 1, 'key': 'val2'},
 {'another_key': 'a', 'count': 3, 'key': 'val1'},
 {'another_key': 'c', 'count': 2, 'key': 'val3'}]
```

If you want the list sorted in descending order of counts then you can use the `Counter.most_common` method:

```
ordered = [{'key': t[0], 'another_key': t[1], 'count': val} 
    for t, val in groups.most_common()]
pprint(ordered)
```

**output**

```
[{'another_key': 'a', 'count': 3, 'key': 'val1'},
 {'another_key': 'c', 'count': 2, 'key': 'val3'},
 {'another_key': 'd', 'count': 1, 'key': 'val2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = Counter([tuple(a.items()) for a in array])
print(counter)
for tup, count in counter.items():
    print('-----')
    print(tup)
    print(tup[0][1])
    d = dict(tup)
    print(d)
    print(d['another_key'])
    print(count)
```

Result:

```
Counter({(('another_key', 'a'), ('key', 'val1')): 3, (('another_key', 'c'), ('key', 'val3')): 2, (('another_key', 'd'), ('key', 'val2')): 1})
-----
(('another_key', 'c'), ('key', 'val3'))
c
{'another_key': 'c', 'key': 'val3'}
c
2
-----
(('another_key', 'a'), ('key', 'val1'))
a
{'another_key': 'a', 'key': 'val1'}
a
3
-----
(('another_key', 'd'), ('key', 'val2'))
d
{'another_key': 'd', 'key': 'val2'}
d
1
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I use loop for this counter?

Comment: @user2503775 I don't understand. A Counter is a dict so you can use it in the same way. What do you want to do and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: After the group finishes, I need to use the key+another_key. See what I had before: `for key,count in groups: do something with key and another key..`

Comment: This answer doesn't give the format provided in the question

Comment: @Adirio well I didn't think OP needed to be spoonfed literally everything.

Comment: What if I have 3 keys in orginal array and want only 2, can I also use this `tuple`?

Comment: @AlexHall well he asked for a format, list and dict comprehension are hard to understand when coming from other languages

Comment: @user2503775 you would need to filter the tuple with another generator

Comment: @user2503775 just use `(item['key'], item['another_key'])` like in other answers.

Comment: Thank you! it was realy nice to know about the `tuple` option.

Comment: @user2503775 The 3 solutions proposed by Alex Hall, PM2 Ring and me use tuples, the difference is the previous two have at least two items inside parenthesis which make a short representation of a tuple, also called literal representation. This solution does not have multiple fields inside the parenthesis as it is contructed from an iterator, thus using the literal representation would not work as they would just be parenthesis and the long representation needs to be used, writting tuple

Answer (score -1):

Add a bit more to your comprehension:

```
groups = Counter(a[key] for a in array for key in a)
```

And it can be a generator expression rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: But I get `Counter({'a': 3, 'val1': 3, 'c': 2, 'val3': 2, 'd': 1, 'val2': 1})`

Comment: The `key` and `another_key` are non-splittable pairs, you are counting each of them separately.

Comment: @Adirio - This answer gives a reasonable and useful result as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You are splitting `key` and `another_key` into two different entries inside the counter. Think of them as a composite key, both together form the key, not each of them alone. Imagine you have chapters (`key`) with sub-chapters (`another_key`) and different paragraphs in each of them and you want to count the number of paragraphs in each sub-chapter, your solution would have the count of every pharagraph in the first sub-chapter of any chapter or the ammount of paragraphs in a chapter, but not the number of paragraphs of the first sub-chapter of the first chapter.